# Optimization of loops - How to implement list-comprehensions

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am writing a function, get_moduli,
that takes an arbitrary number of lists of Cartesian coordinates as input,
and returns the radii as a list. The function behaves correctly but is a bit too long,
and could perhaps be optimized using list comprehensions. Any suggestions?

```
# Sample input:
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 3, 5]
z = [1, 4, 7]


def get_moduli(*args):
    """Moduli of arbitrary number of vectors."""
    moduli = []
    for container in args:
        for i in range(len(container)):
            container[i - 1] = container[i - 1] ** 2
    for i in range(len(args)):
        sum_of_squares = 0
        for j in range(len(args[i])):
            sum_of_squares += args[j][i]
        moduli.append(sum_of_squares ** .5)
    return moduli


# Run function on sample input:
get_moduli(x, y, z)

# Desired outcome should be as follows:
# [(1 ** 2 + 1 ** 2 + 1 ** 2) ** .5,
#  (2 ** 2 + 3 ** 2 + 4 ** 2) ** .5,
#  (3 ** 2 + 5 ** 2 + 7 ** 2) ** .5]
```

Returns correct answer:
`[1.7320508075688772, 5.385164807134504, 9.1104335791443]`

But how could this function be simplified?

Comment: `Returns correct answer` - I doubt. Shouldn't modulus of `x` be 3.74? Moreover, your code gives me `IndexError` for the case `get_moduli(x, y, z, [1, 2, 3])`.

Comment: @Poolka The first modulus would be the square root of the sum of the first elements in x, y & z in the example above

Comment: `container[i - 1] = container[i - 1] ** 2` this line will raise an index error. Shouldn't `for j in range(len(args))` be `for j in range(len(args[i]))`?

Comment: Can you write down as a mathematical expression what you actually want to calculate? The Euclidean norm of a vector? Your reply to @Poolka suggests that the vectors in your example are supposed to be [x[0],y[0],z[0]], [x[1], y[1], z[1]] etc. Is this the case and if so, why did you choose this representation?

Comment: @kuro thanks for the tip, I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: @ctenar see example in the end of code snippet that has now been added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two functions do what you want:

```
def modulus(v):
    return sum(vi*vi for vi in v)**0.5

def zipped_modulus(*args):
    return [modulus(t) for t in list(zip(*args))]

zipped_modulus(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 2):

Took me some time to figure out that your matrix is transposed of what i thought

you can use this

```
def modulus(*args)
    return [sum([v**2 for v in vector])**.5 for vector in zip(*args)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Sample input:
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 3, 5]
z = [1, 4, 7]


def get_moduli1(*args):
    return list(map(lambda x: sum(y**2 for y in x)**0.5 , zip(*args)))


print(get_moduli1(x, y, z))
```

output

```
 [1.7320508075688772, 5.385164807134504, 9.1104335791443]
```